# How can I select text in an entry

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am working with net maui and I need to select all the text of an entry after having selected an element from a picker, the c# code is :

```
void piElemento_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        int SelectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;
        if (SelectedIndex !=-1)
        {
            enGrados.Focus(); // Focus de Entry
            enGrados.CursorPosition = 0;
            enGrados.SelectionLength = enGrados.Text.Lenght;
        }
            
    }
```

After selecting an element it is positioned in the entry with focus, but the text is not selected. What can I do to solve this problem.
I'm running the app for Mac Catalist.
Thanks

Comment: This may related to [Can't select all text on UITextView using mac catalyst APIs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15156). This looks like just how Mac Catalyst handles events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're encountering often relates to the sequence in which the code gets executed. Sometimes, you might need to give the UI a brief moment to update before proceeding with text selection. One common way to handle this is to introduce a short delay using Task.Delay.

```
async void piElemento_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var picker = (Picker)sender;
    int SelectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

    if (SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        enGrados.Focus();
        await Task.Delay(100); 

        enGrados.CursorPosition = 0;
        enGrados.SelectionLength = enGrados.Text.Length;  
    }
}
```